# Quadratic residues are so much fun!

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

### Definitions

#### Quadratic residues

An integer \$r\$ is called a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo \$n\$ if there exists an integer \$x\$ such that:

$$x^2\equiv r \pmod n$$

The set of quadratic residues modulo \$n\$ can be simply computed by looking at the results of \$x^2 \bmod n\$ for \$0 \le x \le \lfloor n/2\rfloor\$.

#### The challenge sequence

We define \$a_n\$ as the minimum number of occurrences of the same value \$(r_0-r_1+n) \bmod n\$ for all pairs \$(r_0,r_1)\$ of quadratic residues modulo \$n\$.

The first 30 terms are:

$$1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 7, 2$$

This is [A316975](http://oeis.org/A316975) (submitted by myself).

### Example: \$n=10\$

The quadratic residues modulo \$10\$ are \$0\$, \$1\$, \$4\$, \$5\$, \$6\$ and \$9\$.

For each pair \$(r_0,r_1)\$ of these quadratic residues, we compute \$(r_0-r_1+10) \bmod 10\$, which leads to the following table (where \$r_0\$ is on the left and \$r_1\$ is on the top):

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
& 0 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 9\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & \color{blue}7 & 6 & 5 & \color{green}2\\
4 & 4 & \color{magenta}3 & 0 & 9 & \color{red}8 & 5\\
5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 6\\
6 & 6 & 5 & \color{green}2 & 1 & 0 & \color{blue}7\\
9 & 9 & \color{red}8 & 5 & 4 & \color{magenta}3 & 0
\end{array}$$

The minimum number of occurrences of the same value in the above table is \$2\$ (for \$\color{green}2\$, \$\color{magenta}3\$, \$\color{blue}7\$ and \$\color{red}8\$). Therefore \$a_{10}=2\$.

### Your task

- You may either:

  - take an integer \$n\$ and print or return \$a_n\$ (either 0-indexed or 1-indexed)
  - take an integer \$n\$ and print or return the \$n\$ first terms of the sequence
  - take no input and print the sequence forever
- Your code must be able to process any of the 50 first values of the
  sequence in less than 1 minute.
- Given enough time and memory, your code must theoretically work for any positive integer supported by your language.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: Grats on getting a sequence published on OEIS!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Thanks. :) (As a matter of fact, I usually avoid posting an OEIS sequence as-is as a challenge, but I guess that's OK for this one.)

Comment: Doesn't the `+n` inside the `(...)mod n` have no effect? If so it's very weird that is part of the definition.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Actually, I made a similar remark in the draft version of the sequence and suggested that it was removed. But I didn't find any clear consensus, nor did I get any feedback about that. (And I seem to recall having seen other sequences with `(some_potentially_negative_value + n) mod n`.) I think it's better to have it in a programming challenge, though, since [the sign of the result depends on the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation).

Comment: @Arnauld Could you not choose `some_potentially_negative_value < -n`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech This can't happen here, since both \$r_0\$ and \$r_1\$ are in \$[0..n-1]\$. But generally speaking, yes: this formula holds only for \$x\ge -n\$.

Comment: @Arnauld I think \$r_1\$ is only defined modulo \$n\$.

Comment: I've tried to find a direct formula without success. The sequence is multiplicative and on primes it equals `a_p = round(p/4)`, which gives us the values for all squarefree numbers. But the situation seems complicated on powers of primes, and the 3 mod 4 and 1 mod 4 cases need to be handled separately.

Comment: \$(r_0-r_1+n)\mod n=(r_0-r_1)\mod n\$, no?

Comment: Looking forward to your JS solution to this; just tried it myself after a long night's work and gave myself brainache! Probably doesn't help that I still don't fully the challenge.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, not in all languages - [e.g., JavaScript](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP12DS8NU10JT1dBAB8zSNjQAcbg0//8HAA)

Comment: @Shaggy Yeah, some languages don't follow the definition exactly.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
:UG\u&-G\8#uX<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yrUPaZUTdc9xkK5NMLm/39jAwA) Or [verify the first 30 values](https://tio.run/##Dcs7CsJAAEXR/m4jYCfMe/MXSyEbUJCQIum1M@DuR09/3vvnNbZxeczrcTrPa5uO53Xclu99CBNJZAqVRkcBCRlFlFBGBVXUUMcB/49xxAlnXHDFDXdi@AE).

#### Explanation

```
:      % Implicit input. Range
U      % Square, element-wise
G      % Push input again
\      % Modulo, element-wise
u      % Unique elements
&-     % Table of pair-wise differences
G      % Push input
\      % Modulo, element-wise
8#u    % Number of occurrences of each element
X<     % Minimum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-g`, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

Spent too long figuring out what the challenge was actually about, ran out of time for further golfing :\

Outputs the `n`th term in the sequence. Starts struggling when input `>900`.

```
õ_²uUÃâ ïÍmuU
£è¥XÃn
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9V+ydVXD4iDvzW11VQqj6KVYw24=&input=NTAKLWc=) or [check results for 0-50](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9V+ydVXD4iDvzW11VQqj6KVYw24gZw==&input=NTEKLW0=)

---

### Explanation

```
                  :Implicit input of integer U
õ                 :Range [1,U]
 _                :Map
  ²               :  Square
   uU             :  Modulo U
     Ã            :End map
      â           :Deduplicate
        ï         :Cartesian product of the resulting array with itself
         Í        :Reduce each pair by subtraction
          m       :Map
           uU     :  Absolute value of modulo U
\n                :Reassign to U
£                 :Map each X
 è                :  Count the elements in U that are
  ¥X              :   Equal to X
    Ã             :End map
     n            :Sort
                  :Implicitly output the first element in the array
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Dennis (forcing dyadic interpretation with a leading `ð`)
-2 more also thanks to Dennis (since the pairs may be de-duplicated we can avoid an `R` and a `2`)

```
ðp²%QI%ĠẈṂ
```

A monadic link accepting a positive integer which yields a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//w7BwwrIlUUklxKDhuojhuYL///8xMA)** Or see [the first 50 terms](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//w7BwwrIlUUklxKDhuojhuYL/NTDDh@KCrP8).

#### How?

```
ðp²%QI%ĠẈṂ - Link: integer, n                   e.g. 6
ð          - start a new dyadic chain - i.e. f(Left=n, Right=n)
 p         - Cartesian product of (implicit ranges)  [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[6,6]]
  ²        - square (vectorises)                     [[1,1],[1,4],[1,9],[1,16],[1,25],[1,36],[4,1],[4,4],[4,9],[4,16],[4,25],[4,36],[9,1],[9,4],[9,9],[9,16],[9,25],[9,36],[16,1],[16,4],[16,9],[16,16],[16,25],[16,36],[25,1],[25,4],[25,9],[25,16],[25,25],[25,36],[36,1],[36,4],[36,9],[36,16],[36,25],[36,36]]
   %       - modulo (by Right) (vectorises)          [[1,1],[1,4],[1,3],[1,4],[1,1],[1,0],[4,1],[4,4],[4,3],[4,4],[4,1],[4,0],[3,1],[3,4],[3,3],[3,4],[3,1],[3,0],[4,1],[4,4],[4,3],[4,4],[4,1],[4,0],[1,1],[1,4],[1,3],[1,4],[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,4],[0,3],[0,4],[0,1],[0,0]]
    Q      - de-duplicate                            [[1,1],[1,4],[1,3],[1,0],[4,1],[4,4],[4,3],[4,0],[3,1],[3,4],[3,3],[3,0],[0,1],[0,4],[0,3],[0,0]]
     I     - incremental differences (vectorises)    [0,3,2,-1,-3,0,-1,-4,-2,1,0,-3,1,4,3,0]
      %    - modulo (by Right) (vectorises)          [0,3,2,5,3,0,5,2,4,1,0,3,1,4,3,0]
       Ġ   - group indices by value                  [[1,6,11,16],[10,13],[3,8],[2,5,12,15],[9,14],[4,7]]
        Ẉ  - length of each                          [3,2,2,4,2,2]
         Ṃ - minimum                                 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> <s>20</s> <s>15</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LnI%êãÆI%D.m¢
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Mr. Xcoder*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ89T9fCqw4sPt3mquujlHlr0/9Ca/0aWAA) or [verify the first 99 test cases (in about 3 seconds)](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/8wNWFiMWX/0YJHTj8iIOKGkiAiP05VTsOQ/0xuWCXDqsOjw4ZYJUQubcKi/8KsLP8). (NOTE: The Python legacy version is used on TIO instead of the new Elixir rewrite. It's about 10x faster, but requires a trailing `¬` (head) because `.m` returns a list instead of a single item, which I've added to the footer.)

**Explanation:**

```python
L       # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 n      # Square each
  I%    # And then modulo each with the input
    ê   # Sort and uniquify the result (faster than just uniquify apparently)
 ã      # Create pairs (cartesian product with itself)
  Æ     # Get the differences between each pair
   I%   # And then modulo each with the input
D.m     # Take the least frequent number (numbers in the legacy version)
   ¢    # Take the count it (or all the numbers in the legacy version, which are all the same)
        # (and output it implicitly)
```

Comment: `Ýns%ÙãÆI%D.m¢`. (not in legacy, in the new version)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah, I'm an idiot to use `Dâ` instead of `ã`.. >.> And didn't knew the `.m` acted differently in the Elixir rewrite. I originally had the new version, but switched to the legacy after I noticed the `¥` wasn't working (which you've fixed with the `Æ`). I still use the legacy on TIO though, because it's way faster for this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>202</s> <s>200</s> <s>190</s> <s>188</s> <s>187</s> 186 bytes

- Saved <s>two</s> <s>twelve</s> <s>fourteen</s> fifteen bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).
- Saved a byte.

```c
Q(u,a){int*d,*r,A[u],t,i[a=u],*c=i,k;for(;a--;k||(*c++=a*a%u))for(k=a[A]=0,r=i;r<c;)k+=a*a%u==*r++;for(r=c;i-r--;)for(d=i;d<c;++A[(u+*r-*d++)%u]);for(t=*A;++a<u;t=k&&k<t?k:t)k=A[a];u=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BagMxDER/pQQ22JIMOdcrij8hZ7MHYSetcbstwqaHpN@@dZbcBt6bgUnuPaVtO5tOYm9lbZAJlELsCzUqUXgESFyo@uu3Gi/O@Xq/G0iILCBTt/YBKksMC59IuXidk7f1yZlBEfe2cvLF6ZjYO3moeaiIIZqOoA4yop36Yne9MYQBZe6@cT0e69ze6muzlUOUxXdu/m/7krKa1d5@P8rnZYQfHS@u5jBlejnQ2axj0Q7vHw)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cool; declaring another integer actually allows to save another byte.

Comment: @ceilingcat I think those expressions are not equivalent as I need the smallest positive modulo residue.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
def f(n):r={i*i%n for i in range(n)};r=[(s-t)%n for s in r for t in r];return min(map(r.count,r))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcwxCsJAEEbhq0wjzEgU1tKQk4QUQXd1ivy7TCZFEM@@ymJl9@CDV3Z/ZlxqvcdEiSFXG1561AMoZSMlBdmMR/zSu7dh5PXk8tO1aUtvOfUWfTPQouBlLmznW97gnYnUYgqnMbHK/zt0IchUPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 29 bytes

```
{&/#:'=,/x!r-\:r:?x!i*i:!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/dqlpNX9lK3VZHv0KxSDfGqsjKvkIxUyvTSrGi9n@JVbVKdGVdkVWaQoV1Qn62tUZCWmJmjnWFdaV1kWZsLVeaVXW6uqE2UC1XSbSxgbWhgpGCIRgaQVlGCsZA0ljBBMwzAfJNwaJmQAihQSrNFYxi/wMA)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`!x` integers from `0` to `x-1`

`i:` assign to `i`

`x!` mod `x`

`?` unique

`r:` assign to `r`

`-\:` subtract from each left

`r-\:r` matrix of all differences

`x!` mod `x`

`,/` concatenate the rows of the matrix

`=` group, returns a dictionary from unique values to lists of occurrence indices

`#:'` length of each value in the dictionary

`&/` minimum

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 64 bytes

```
Min[Last/@Tally@Mod[Tuples[Union@Mod[Range@#^2,#],2].{1,-1},#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@983My/aJ7G4RN8hJDEnp9LBNz8lOqS0ICe1ODo0LzM/DywQlJiXnuqgHGekoxyrYxSrV22oo2tYC@TEqv13yY8OKMrMK4nOU9C1U0iLzouN1VGoztNRMNRRMDaojf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 88 bytes

```ruby
->n{(z=(w=(0..n).map{|x|x*x%n}|[]).product(w).map{|a,b|(a-b)%n}).map{|c|z.count(c)}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDkAwEAA/Q7IVNnVveYg4tBWJgyWiUWzfXg7iOjOZzdszjTpVDd1waTg0SEQSOJv15sChCDlF7nqB67YM3u1wfNKUlsFUVrzBhxxf6BZPOzgRcZ4oJqgRayn/YdYoNXahV6otY3oA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```apl
{⌊/⊢∘≢⌸∊⍵|∘.-⍨∪⍵|×⍨⍳⍵+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9XTpP@pa9KhjxqPORY96djzq6HrUu7UGyNfTfdS74lHHKhD38HQQu3czkK1tWPs/Daj3UW8fxJiu5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/7RDKwy1gTqMDQA)

Prefix direct function. Uses `⎕IO←0`.

Thanks to Cows quack for 4 bytes!

#### How:

```apl
{⌊/⊢∘≢⌸∊⍵|∘.-⍨∪⍵|×⍨⍳⍵+1} ⍝ Dfn, argument ⍵

                   ⍳⍵+1 ⍝ Range [0..⍵]
                 ×⍨     ⍝ Squared
               ⍵|       ⍝ Modulo ⍵
              ∪         ⍝ Unique
          ∘.-⍨          ⍝ Pairwise subtraction table
       ∊⍵|              ⍝ Modulo ⍵, flattened
      ⌸                 ⍝ Key; groups indices (in its ⍵) of values (in its ⍺).
   ⊢∘≢                  ⍝ Tally (≢) the indices. This returns the number of occurrences of each element.
 ⌊/                      ⍝ Floor reduction; returns the smallest number.
```

Comment: Couple of small byte-shavings, `2*⍨` → `×⍨`, `r←¨⊂r` → `∘.-⍨`, `{≢⍵}` → `⊢∘≢`